# How to set input value based on other input in Laravel Livewire?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have to number inputs,

1. rate
2. reverse of rate

what I want to do:

when a user insert rate, it should calculate(1/rate) the reverse, and fill it in reverse input.

```
    <!-- Rate -->
    <x-input-group type="number" min="0"  step="0.0001"/>

    <!-- Reverse -->
    <x-input-group type="number min="0" step="0.0001"/>
```

I know that it should do something like this:

```
    <!-- Rate -->
    <x-input-group type="number" min="0" wire:focusout="reverse"  step="0.0001"/>

    <!-- Reverse -->
    <x-input-group type="number min="0" step="0.0001"/>
```

and in my component:

```
public function reverse()
{
    $reverse = floatval(1 / $this->rate);
    // here I don't know how to change reverse input value
}
```

Now, how to change reverse value in the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
    <!-- Rate -->
    <x-input-group type="number" wire:model.lazy="rate" min="0"  step="0.0001"/>

    <!-- Reverse -->
    <x-input-group type="number wire:model="reverse" min="0" step="0.0001"/>

// in component 

public $rate, $reverse;

public function updatedRate($value)
{
   $this->reverse = floatval(1 / $this->rate);
}
```